# Why wont it let me add a legend to my graph on ggplot2 in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I would like to add a legend to this but am struggling to find out how. Can someone please help?

```
  df1 <- data.frame(Rate=rnorm(10, 500, 100), Damage=rnorm(10, 50, 15))
  x1 <- data.frame(R=rnorm(20, 550, 50), V=rnorm(20, 35, 10))

  ggplot(df1,aes(x=Rate,y=Damage)) +
  geom_smooth(method="auto",se=FALSE) +
  geom_smooth(data=x1, mapping=aes(x=R, y=V), 
  method="auto",col="firebrick",se=FALSE) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim=c(0,1000), ylim=c(0, 100)) +
  ggtitle("", subtitle="PPS post-emergence") +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 100, 20),) +
  xlab("Rate (mg/Ha)") +
  ylab("")
```

Comment: Linked question is very similar to yours. Add `aes` for each `geom_smooth` with `color = ...` and specify wanted color with `scale_color_manual` (in case you needed legend for color).

Comment: Why not rbind then plot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do what you want is to merge your data. But you can also do a manual color mapping. I'll show you both below.

### Without merging your data

You want to create a manual color scale. The trick is to pass the color in `aes` then add a `scale_color_manual` to map names to colors.

```
ggplot(df1,aes(x=Rate,y=Damage)) +
  geom_smooth(aes(col = "val1"), method="auto",se=FALSE) +
  geom_smooth(data=x1, mapping=aes(x=R, y=V, col="val2"), 
              method="auto",se=FALSE) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim=c(0,1000), ylim=c(0, 100)) +
  ggtitle("", subtitle="PPS post-emergence") +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 100, 20),) +
  xlab("Rate (mg/Ha)") +
  ylab("") +
  scale_color_manual("My legend", values=c("val1" = "firebrick", 
                                           "val2" = "steelblue"))
```

[image: Plot with legend]

#### Less lines by using labs

By the way, there is a simpler way to set the title (or subtitle) and axis labels with `labs`. You don't have to pass a title so you gain some vertical space and passing `NULL` (instead of `""`) as the y label actually removes it which gains some horizontal space.

Below, the picture is the same size but the graph occupies a larger part of it.

```
ggplot(df1,aes(x=Rate,y=Damage)) +
  geom_smooth(aes(col = "val1"), method="auto",se=FALSE) +
  geom_smooth(data=x1, mapping=aes(x=R, y=V, col="val2"), 
              method="auto",se=FALSE) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim=c(0,1000), ylim=c(0, 100)) +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 100, 20),) +
  labs(subtitle="PPS post-emergence", 
       x = "Rate (mg/Ha)",
       y = NULL) +
  scale_color_manual("My legend", values=c("val1" = "firebrick", 
                                           "val2" = "steelblue"))
```

[image: Plot using labs instead of ggtitle]

### Merging your data

The best way of doing it would actually be to merge your data while keeping track of the source, then use `source` as the color. Much cleaner but not always possible.

```
df <- bind_rows(
  mutate(df1, source="df1"),
  x1 %>% rename(Rate = R, Damage = V) %>%
    mutate(source="x1")
)

ggplot(df, aes(x=Rate, y=Damage, col=source)) +
  geom_smooth(method="auto", se=FALSE) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim=c(0,1000), ylim=c(0, 100)) +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 100, 20),) +
  labs(subtitle="PPS post-emergence", 
       x = "Rate (mg/Ha)",
       y = NULL)
```

[image]

Comment: A very helpful answer. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

We could row bind then plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

set.seed(1)
df1 <- data.frame(Rate=rnorm(10, 500, 100), Damage=rnorm(10, 50, 15))
x1 <- data.frame(R=rnorm(20, 550, 50), V=rnorm(20, 35, 10))

plotDat <- rbind(df1 %>% transmute(x = Rate, y = Damage, grp = "df1"),
                 x1 %>% transmute(x = R, y = V, grp = "x1"))

ggplot(plotDat, aes(x, y, col = grp)) +
  geom_smooth(se = FALSE)
```

[image]